# How do you use translate “You can't miss this opportunity"?

Tags: grammar

So, I'm trying to figure out how to encourage someone to take a risk/try something new in Chinese. In English we often use the phrase "miss an opportunity" as in "You can't miss this opportunity!". But how would that translate directly into chinese?

For example, could I say
"我不能错过这个机会哦！“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lovely saying in Chinese that fits here

**机不可失，时不再来**

*KEY*

> "don't let an opportunity slip as it may never come again"—opportunity knocks but once

You can just say this phrase to them - it will encourage them to seize the opportunity and do something.

Answer (score 4):

That would mean: I would not miss this opportunity.

Change the 我 to a 你, and remove the 哦.

This will result in: "你不能错过这个机会"

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving advice, you can also say "勿失良機".

As "勿" here is a way to give advice, you cannot use it on yourself, e.g. it is wrong to say "我今次一定勿失良機".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chengyu "机不可失，时不再来", which means "Don't lose a golden opportunity".

Comment: This is the exact same as my answer and posted four hours after...

Comment: Sorry, don't notice that